# Проблема wsl docker

Tags: docker, wsl, wsl2

Я пытался ставить docker на свою систему и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что он не хочет взаимодействовать с wsl. Ядро wsl обновлено до второй версии, но при установки подсистемы она ставится первой версии и никак не хочет переключаться на вторую версию. Под минималки для wsl2 попадает. Проблема именно с версией подсистемы.
P.S: все необходимые настройки в биосе включены. Ставил на другой машину с аналогичной версией windows, все работает нормально.
[image: System]

[image: Min]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла полная переустановка windows с изменением ключа активации на простую pro версию. Восстановление системы до первоначальных настроек вообще никак не помогало устранению ошибок. Отмечу, что дистрибутив был один и тот же.